# Link mat.h in a C++ file

Tags: c++, linux, matlab, compiler-errors, mat

I have to use mat.h for open a .mat file in my C++ code.
My code is that:

```
#include "mat.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {
MATFile *pmat;
pmat = matOpen("ns3Da.mat","r");
return 0;
}
```

The command I use to compile is that:

g++ program.cpp -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/extern/include -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/* -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/extern/lib -o program

The error I obtain is that:

`/tmp/ccSWqTnb.o: In function 'main':
programma_c.cpp:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to 'matOpen'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I use Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Matlab 2012a version.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: You are not linking a required library. You only specify the library search paths.

Comment: ^ --- i.e. add `-lmat` to the build command

Comment: OK, who thought that "mat.h" was a good name for a header? It looks like if someone had had misspelled "math.h"

Answer (score 1):

The `-L` flag in compilation specifies the path to search for libraries. `-l` flag should be used to specify the name of library without `lib`, for instance, in your case `-lmat`. So your compilation command should be something like

```
g++ program.cpp -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/extern/include -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64 -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/extern/lib -lmat -o program
```

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmat
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: where is `libmat` located in your system

Comment: In /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64 there is libmat.so

Comment: I have updated the answer accordingly, Please give a trial

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: warning: libmwfl.so, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmat.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libmwi18n.so, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libmat.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
......
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: where is `libmwfl.so` in ur system?

Comment: Also `libmwi18n.so`

Comment: In /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64

Comment: ur last but one comment says it is not available at  /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64

Comment: You have an idea of how to make them available, I see them all in the / usr / local / MATLAB / R2012a / bin / glnxa64 folder

Comment: @SaraSavio You got this done? I have the same issue in Windows.