# #include <mat.h> in Visual Studio Code does not work

Tags: c++, windows, matlab, gcc, visual-studio-code

I want to use some matlab code in c++. For example I want to read matlab files directly in my c++ IDE. There are some pretty cool c++ packages that allow you to handle the most problems I face.

But I fail to use these packages. It seems like I cannot #include the packages correctly. The error looks always something like "undefined reference to `matOpen'".

I use Visual studio Code and mingw as c++ compiler on Windows.

1. I tried different notations:

```
#include < mat.h>

#include "mat.h"
```

and also, because I use c++, `#include < cmath>` which does not work but gives a different error:

> "'matOpen' was not declared in this scope".

2. I tried compiling in cmd

I also tried to compile the files in the command prompt. I read [here](https://medium.com/@larmalade/gcc-the-hard-way-how-to-include-functions-from-the-math-library-1cfe60f24a7a) that there might be linkage problems and tried to *"add the -lm flag to the gcc compiler command in order to use math functions in your C code"* without success.

I am not an expert with c++ nor cmd and it might be possible that I made some mistakes with the correct compile command. The [help](https://medium.com/@larmalade/gcc-the-hard-way-how-to-include-functions-from-the-math-library-1cfe60f24a7a) from above uses ubuntu and c and not windows and c++. Are there any differences I have to pay attention to in order compile successfully?

3. Different paths

I also tried to relocate the file mat.h to the different locations like the path of the project or the compiler path or write the full path to mat.h in the include statement.

A similar ([Link mat.h in a C++ file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564442/link-mat-h-in-a-c-file)) question is for ubuntu and did not help me either.

My code is pretty simple:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <mat.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    MATFile *pmat;
    pmat = matOpen("test.mat","r");
    return 0;
}
```

The error message I get:

```
cd "c:\projects\test\" ; if ($?) { g++ test.cpp -o test } ; if ($?) { .\test }
C:\user_path\AppData\Local\Temp\ccKUxfwi.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `matOpen'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I would appreciate any help. I want to use some more packages but it is probably the same solution for all.

Comment: The final error means you are missing a link to some library. `g++ test.cpp -o test` does not specify a library so its understandable.

Comment: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-functions-from-c-1.html

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: I believe this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564442/link-mat-h-in-a-c-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564442/link-mat-h-in-a-c-file) should help as it tells you what library is needed. `-lmat` you will have to update the paths to the library from that example to match where you have installed your matlib libraries. So `-L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64` will need to be changed

Comment: You need to use the `mex` script to build these programs: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/building-on-windows-operating-systems.html

Comment: @drescherjm how do I specify a library?
I tried g++ -o test test.cpp -I\Path -L\Path -L\Path 
Did not work but there might be a problem with the paths. I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom nice article I have already read but I have the same problem with #include "MatlabEngine.hpp"
#include "MatlabDataArray.hpp"

Comment: The include errors mean you need to set the include path.

Comment: `-lmat` specifies the library. You should spend some time learning how to use an external library with `gcc` since this appears to be your main issue.

Comment: From the linked example: `-I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/extern/include`  sets the include path. Again on a modern system your path will be different. I assume you are not using a matlab version from 2012 on a linux system.

Comment: `-I\Path` I am not sure about using \ versus / you may need to quote if you use \ instead of the expected /

Comment: @drescherjm thanks for your help. Unfortunately I did not manage to make it work. I tried to teach myself how to use g++ command correctly. Tried all combinations with -I,-L and -l but it did not work neither did it work if I set the include path and library directories in VSCode or Visual Studio manually. Also checked for enviromental variables. 
- if I use -lmat at the end it gives me an error "lmat not found". lmat refers to libmat.lib is that correct? Tried to specify libmat.lib in the command but also no success.

Comment: When I use g++ -o test -c test.cpp , -c tries to link and to compile it gives no error message but does not create and executable file.
For a simple hello world programm -c works just fine but when I try to include some header like <mat.h> I cannot execute the output file

Answer (score 1):

#include <mat.h> is correct as it avoids the "not declared" error.

The "undefined reference" is a link-time error, it has nothing to do with the #include statement (the message is emitted by ld, not gcc).

Check that you added the (precompiled) library in your project.