# What is the right way of reading MATLAB formatted data file in C++

Tags: c++, macos, matlab, dynamic-linking

I am trying to read a MATLAB formatted data file (data.mat) file in C++. I referred to the following post "[Link mat.h in a C++ file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564442/link-mat-h-in-a-c-file)" and tried the given example code.

```
using namespace std;
int main() {
MATFile *pmat;
pmat = matOpen("data.mat","r");
return 0;
}
```

From the answer to the post, I ran the example code using the following command,

```
Command:
g++ main.cpp -o out -I/Applications/MATLAB_R2019a.app/extern/include -L/Applications/MATLAB_R2019a.app/extern/lib -lmat

Output:
ld: library not found for -lmat
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

In order to fix this, I copied `'mat.h', 'matrix.h' and 'tmwtypes.h'` to the code directory. But, now when I am running the code, I am getting a different error and I am not able to find any solution for this.

```
Command:
g++ main.cpp -o out

Output:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_matOpen_800", referenced from:
      _main in main-d0f06c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can someone please help me with this.
I am using Mac OS Mojave. Thank you.

Comment: You should add a proper tags to your question. The issue is more of `linker` related. Adding an OS tag will be great.

Comment: Well... I did not give you a down-vote. To confirm that you may see my downvote as of now. The SO user can not downvote more then twice. So the last one was mine :P

Comment: Do you have a `/Applications/MATLAB_R2019a.app/extern/lib/libmat.dylib`? This is what you are telling your build system to link to. The linker error says this file doesn’t exist. In your second try you didn’t link to the library, and therefore the linker couldn’t find the symbols defined in the library.

Comment: No, I only have ```maci64``` present in the ```/Applications/MATLAB_R2019a.app/extern/lib/```. I followed this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564442/link-mat-h-in-a-c-file) but then I found that libmat is not present in my system so I copied the header files to my working directory. But, since I am including the header file which is present in the same directory, shouldn't it link while compiling? @CrisLuengo

Comment: If you don’t have the library, you can’t link to the library. Did you look inside the `maci64` directory? I think you might find the library in there. If so, all you need to do is adjust the `-L` option in your compile command to point to the directory that contains the `libmat` library.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I already looked for `libmat`. I also did search through the entire MATLAB_R2019a.app directory, but `libmat` is not present there. I will try to download externally and try again.

Comment: You *should* have this library with a normal MATLAB installation. It might be in the `bin` directory too. It’s location is different on every platform, but it is always there. On MacOS it will have a `.dylib` extension.

Comment: That's one strange thing I'm facing. I searched the entire directory for libmat.dylib but it's not present. I think I should reinstall MATLAB and check.

Answer (score -2):

I had never used `MacOS` on a PC. I even don't know if the `OS` called same name on every device type. What you see here, is a runtime linkage problem.

You pass flags to the linker that tell the linker where to find symbols and what symbols there will be. And then the binary is built. But at runtime, the `ld`(Binary executable file linker/loader. It may be same linker/loader that had produced your particular application) **will** search for dynamic symbols at the places that are standard to the OS.

As I said, I'm not used to MacOS. I use Linux now. For example **my** Linux uses `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib` path to search for dynamic libraries. The way the `ld` program searches for the symbols can be configured in few ways.

For example `Linux` has `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and MacOS has a `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` envinronment variables. See this question and answers: [Is it OK to use DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH on Mac OS X? And, what's the dynamic library search algorithm with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3146274/8339821). BTW, I do agree with many posts there that editing an envinronment variable is a best way to solve this situation.

There are also a well known `-Wl,--rpath` flag for the linker. It explicitly tells to add a search path to the application file. I think this method fits more if you a developer and are experimenting with your code before installing it to a proper location.

My answer to this question will be such, that, you should read the manuals. Type `man ld` in your terminal and see what your options are.

**Update**

Well, at my `Linux`, the loader is called `ld.so` and linker is `ld`. The update is just to answer the comment.

Comment: It is a compile-time linker error, not a run-time error. `ld` is the static compile-time linker. `ldd` would be the dynamic run-time linker (it has a different name on MacOS, but no matter).

Comment: In either case, `ld` is the static linker and OP’s error messages happened during the creation of the binary, not during its running.

Comment: not that smart to tell you're downvoting others. Moderators may notice and take action.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre They did notice. Next time I just ignore the above comments.

Comment: yes, you do that! (notice the diamond next to my name :))

Comment: I did not regret anything! :)) And the OP did state that i had down-voted him, but i did'nt. Did you delete his comment or he did that? Anyhow, I should remove the OP down-vote sometime soon.